# script tag to import Auth0 causes unexpected token error

Tags: html, reactjs, auth0

when I had the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js" async></script>
```

to my react web apps index.html

I get an error in the console that says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <       auth0.js:1
```

When I remove the script tag this error does not show

What is causing the error?

Comment: The reason for the error is probably your web sever serving some kind of error page that starts with `<html>` which is not valid javascript. This happens because `../node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js` is not a valid path that your web server can resolve. Are you using `create-react-app` or a custom webpack setup?

Comment: I am using create-react-app

Comment: Then this is not how you use javascript libraries with webpack. Use the `import` statement like you do with `react` and other dependencies.

Comment: the auth0 instructions were confusing I thought I needed to install the library with npm and also add the script tag, Do I not need the script tag at all if I am using webpack?

Comment: No you don't need the script tag. If you use the `import` statement in the file you are using it webpack will include it in your app bundle automatically. See my answer too.

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial from the auth0 blog on how to use it with react. I agree that the documentation on this is poor. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is probably your web sever serving some kind of 404 error page that indicates that the web server could not find the requested resource.The html Markup starts with a `<` which comes from the opening `<html>` tag. The browser tries to interpret it as javascript code but `<` is not valid javascript. This is why you get this specific error.

This problem originates from your path `../node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js` which is not a valid path that your web server can resolve.

What you may want is to import `auth0` in the javascript file you want to use it in like this:

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
```

You can also follow [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/react-tutorial-building-and-securing-your-first-app/#Securing-your-React-App) on how to use auth0 with react.

I agree that the auth0 docs are a bit misleading regarding using it with a bundler like webpack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be from the auth0.js, open it in a text editor and search for errors or share it code here for checkup.

Comment: or use the following link https://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate to Validate your JS Code.

Comment: the auth0.js is imported from npm and it is almost 10,000 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried this yet, I'll suggest you add another script tag with a different path. If you don't get an error, then there's a problem with the `auth0.js` file.

Let us know what the outcome is.

Comment: adding another script tag gives me the same error for both scripts